# How to use google homegraph api with my own django cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-home, google-smart-home

I am trying to build a smart-home project and I want to use voice commands to control the smart devices in my home and I found out that I have to use homegraph API for it. So is there anyone who can help me , like I want to use my own django based cloud network for this and there is firebase examples only available on google docs. Please guide me if someone know about it '-'

Answer (score 0):

Django-based I'm assuming is the Python-based framework.

While the conceptual docs may include snippets just in Node.js, you can look at the [REST API pages](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/rest) to get the JSON request/response fields needed to make it work.

To make the development process a bit easier, Google has published the [service protos](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/home/graph/v1) that can be used to programmatically define the Home Graph request, response, and data objects. You can also use the [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) package. This lets you build the the homegraph service using an API like:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

service = build('homegraph', 'v1')
# Here you can call methods on the service object
# service...
```

Then you can [create and execute requests](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/start.md) based on the library documentation.

You will also need to [setup authentication](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/request-sync) before requests will execute.